# The best way to say that a function never vanishes.

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to say that a function $f:M\to \mathbb{R}$,  is non null everywhere, where $M$ is a manifold. I wonder if the expression " f does not vanish on $M$" says exactly that $f$ is non null everywhere on $M$, if it is not the case, what is the best way to right these sentence with a few words. Thanks for help.

Comment: "Is nowhere 0" works pretty well, or "has values in $\mathbb{R}^*$". Lots of choices here, but yes, "$f$ does not vanish on $M$" is indeed a little ambiguous.

Comment: Where is the ambiguity? Vanshing means value zero.

Comment: A sophisticated way to express yourself would be to say that $f$ is an invertible element in the ring of global smooth functions on your manifold: $f\in \mathcal C^\infty(M)^\times$

Comment: @mvw it is not that clear wether "$f$ vanishes on $M$" means that it vanishes at some point of $M$, or everywhere on $M$.

Comment: I often say "$f$ is a never-vanishing map", or "nowhere-vanishing map".

Comment: @CaptainLama I see your point now. Although I believe this is only true for casual language not for mathematical contexts.

Answer (score 0):

How about "$f$ is never zero", or "$f$ is non-zero everywhere on $M$".

Personally, I don't like using the word "null" here. To me "null" is not a real number. And, to anyone with a programming background, "null" and "zero" are two completely different things.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably say: "$f$ is everywhere non-zero."